# run puppet class only if condition is met

Tags: arrays, if-statement, puppet

I've coded a puppet module that I only want to run if selinux is either enforcing or permissive. If its disabled, I want puppet to ignore the class. I'm having a difficult time though trying to find the right conditional format. Here's what I have so far:

```
 class some-class {

 $selinux='/usr/bin/getenforce'     

 exec { "some command":
      command => "some command",
      onlyif => [ $selinux == Enforcing, $selinux == Permissive' ],
      timeout => 30
      }
      }
```

This does not work on a puppet run and I get a "Could not find command '$selinux'. I've been googling all day but cant seem to find how to structure this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `getenforce` is in `/usr/bin/`?

Try this to verify:

```
root@lab:~# which getenforce
/sbin/getenforce
```

You will also run into several other errors with your code, since you didn't quote your strings, you tried to get a `boolean` from a `string` comparison, etc.

Drop you `$selinux` variable and use only the code below

```
exec {
    "rasg":
        command => "echo rasg > /tmp/rasg.txt",
        onlyif  => "getenforce | egrep -q 'Enforcing|Permissive'",
        path    => [ "/bin", "/sbin", "/usr/bin" ],
        timeout => 30,
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, the idiomatic way to do this would be to create a [*custom fact*](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/fact_overview.html) that determines nodes' SELinux enforcement status.  In your Puppet manifests you would then use an ordinary Puppet conditional based on the value of that fact.  For example,

```
if $selinux_enforcement in ['Permissive', 'Enforcing'] {
  exec { "some command":
    timeout => 30
  }
}
```

But if you want specifically to use the `unless` or [`onlyif`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.3/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif) property of an `Exec` resource to control whether to run that Exec's command, then you have to understand that those properties specify *operating system commands* to run to perform the evaluation.  Their exit codes convey whether to proceed with running the main command.  For a Linux target, using the default Exec provider, `posix`, you might do something like this:

```
exec { "some command":
  path => [ '/bin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/sbin' ],
  timeout => 30,
  onlyif => 'bash -c "case $(getenforce) in Enforcing|Permissive) exit 0;; *) exit 1;; esac"' ,
}
```

---

As an aside, do note that the SELinux software suite typically contains a command `selinuxenabled`, which addresses the question more directly than `getenforce` does.  Aimed at use in scripts, this command conveys its result via its exit status, so it might be a better candidate for your `onlyif`, simplifying it to just:

```
  onlyif => 'selinuxenabled'
```